# Why/How is a class method accessible to an array of records only through an association in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, active-relation

Consider a simple example, where we have 2 models, Article and Category.

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category

  def self.search(title)
    where(:title => title)
  end
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
end
```

Now, on the rails console :

```
Article.all.search('test article')
```

As expected returns an error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `search' for #<Array:0x9aa207c>
```

But when I do this

```
Category.first.articles.search('test article')
```

returns a set of records!

This prompts a check on the classes of

```
 Article.all
```

and

```
Category.first.articles
```

both returning the **Array** class.

Obviously, Article's class method 'search' is being inducted in run time and prompting a 'correct' return of records when accessed through its association (Category) but behaving otherwise when accessed by the class itself (Article).

So, What's happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because when you perform `.all` the query is actually executed, so the object returned will be a basic array. However, when you perform `Category.first`, it will return a Category object, then `articles` is actually making use of `ActiveRecord::Reflection::AssociationReflection` and doing an extension of an Array. For example, in `rails c` try:

```
Category.first.articles.ancestors
```

vs

```
Category.first.articles.all.ancestors #throws an error
```

The second one throws an error, because at this point the object is just a simple Array.  The first, however, is made up of something like this:

```
Article(...), ActiveRecord::Base, ActiveRecord::Reflection, Object (and so on)
```

As another example, try this:

```
a = Category.first.articles; ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).select {|k| a < k }
#=> [Object, BasicObject, ActiveRecord::Base]
```

You can see that although it looks like an Array, it's inheriting those other classes.

Comment: Ah! The Lazy Loading. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

```
Article.all
```

This returns an array that's giving you the error as you saw, you're trying to run a class function of `Article` on the `Array` class.

I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to accomplish but you could do this, I think

```
Article.search("soem content")
```

However, I'm not sure if that would return a result, as it might just return an

Comment: Sorry @nvez, but this is not the answer I'm looking for. I'm pretty clear on what I want to accomplish, I'm just really curious as to why or how what i posted is happening.